# how to reuse method by passing different class object?

Tags: java

I have 3 Model classes like Class A, Class B and Class C with same variables and same setter and getter methods .

All three model has getname() and setName(String s) methods.

Another I have controller class where I have created one method. As mention below:

```
public void method1(Object obj)
{
 String s = obj.getname();
}
```

Now I want to call this method by passing model class parameters like  method1(A a), method1(B b)

I want to reuse above method by passing different class instance.

Below i am mentioning whole scenario what I want.

```
 public class Controller {
   public void method1(Object obj)
   {
     String s = obj.getname();
   }

   public void callingMethod()
   {
     if(somecondtion)
     { 
       method1(new A());
     }
     if(somecondtion)
     { 
       method1(new B());
     }

     if(somecondtion)
     { 
       method1(new C());
     }

   }
```

When I do the above code, java is gving me error which says "method could not resolve"

How can I achieve above problem ?

Thanks

Comment: How to reuse exactly means what?

Comment: Yes, i want to resuse this method by passing different class instance

Comment: Use Interface-http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm
In interface you can use abstract method which you can use

Comment: I want to use this method in same class by passing different class instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a general interface with the same signatures. Implement the interface in your classes A,B,C. Now pass the interface. For a general  example

Here is the interface with all the common signatures.

```
interface Root{
   commonMethods();
}
```

here are the classes A,B,C with the implementation of Root

```
class A implements Root{
{
   commonMethods(){
       // implementations
   }
}

class B implements Root{
{
   commonMethods(){
       // implementations
   }
}

class C implements Root{
{
   commonMethods(){
       // implementations
   }
}
```

now in the method where you need to use them

```
public void method1(Root obj)
{
     obj.commonMethods();  // call the method
}
```

So you need to call like

```
method1(new A());
method1(new B());
```

Now the commonMethod() will be called for the A or B class which you passed as parameter

Finally, This design is called [Strategy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

**Update**

My personal suggestion was to implement above solution. But as you don't wan't to use it you can simply use like following

```
public void method1(Object obj)
{
 String s = "";
 if(obj instanceof A)
     s = ((A)obj).getname();
 if(obj instanceof B)
     s = ((B)obj).getname();
 if(obj instanceof C)
     s = ((C)obj).getname();
}
```

Comment: no I don't want like this. I want to use this method in same class by passing different class instance

Comment: @dev09 is there any specific reason for not liking?? may be we can find another solution for you if you describe your scenarion

Comment: but as you see I have passed Object obj to the method. Should i have to cast the Object obj to its specific class instance ?

Comment: scenario is like there are three model classes with same methods and variables. I have one controller class in which I have created one method and I want to reuse that method by passing model class instance in same controller class

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer with scenario. hope this makes you clear

Comment: @dev09 yes i understood the situation .. i hope you found my updated answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

Is this wat you're looking for ?

```
interface IRoot{
string GetName();
}

public void method1(IRoot obj)
{
String s = obj.GetName();
}
```

Or maybe you can just call method with string parameter:

```
public void method1(String s){}
```

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer with scenario. hope this makes you clear